# Regex at the beginning of a string in context

Tags: c#, regex

I've got the following RegEx-Pattern:

```
pattern = @"(?<=\[)[\da-f]{8}(?=\])";
```

It extracts "**f000000f**" out of "**[f000000f] Bar**" correctly, but it should not match on "**Foo [f000000f] Bar**" so i've added the `^` to determine the beginning of the pattern:

```
pattern = @"^(?<=\[)[\da-f]{8}(?=\])";
```

But this pattern doesn't work for both inputs.

Can anybody tell me how to force the first pattern to match only at the beginning of the input-String?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the anchor inside the lookbehind, like this:

```
(?<=^[)[\da-f]{8}(?=])"
```

Otherwise, you wouldn't match `[f000000f]`, because no part of your expression "consumes" the opening square bracket `[`.